# Android Service connecting to another service

Tags: android

I have a situation which  I will try to explain clearly. I have two services, Service A and Service B.
Activity C connects to service A using onBind(). Service A connectes to Service B using a callback object. I want Service A's onbind to not be executed until Service B is connected to Service A. What will be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: See another answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488445/could-a-service-bind-another-service

Answer (score 3):

The right answer is: combine the two services into one.

The next-best answer is: redesign your app such that A is not binding to B, or that C does not care whether A is bound to B.

Comment: I cant combine them both because B is not mine, and A needs B inorder to do its job.

Comment: @techbeast: Then the next-best answer becomes best. You will not find a reliable way to have the binding timing work the way you want. The next-next-best answer is to eliminate A, folding its logic into C.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delay the call from the onBind.  If your service's interaction is such that it may not be ready for use until later, you could have a method on the interface returned by onBind that allows a client to get a callback when it is ready.  (You could even have this set up where the main interface is just "getRealInterface" that takes a callback, which is given the real interface for your service once you are ready to give it.)