# Could a service bind another service

Tags: android

I just want to know could I bind a service from another service. For example, currently I have an `activity A` starting a `service B` and now I just want `service B` to bind and start another `service C`. So does anybody know how to do that? That means could I use the same method for `activity A` to start a service on a service to start another service?

Answer (score 28):

You can call [`bindService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) from a Service exactly the same way you can call it from an Activity. You'll notice from the javadoc that the only place you can't call `bindService` is in a `BroadcastReceiver`. You can use a `ServiceConnection` as well to receive the `Binder`.

Comment: can u guide me to a tutorial of sort that can help me get started on inter service communication in android...regards

Comment: Is this an ok practice to use? If the original `Service` called `startForeground` would the second `Service` also run in the background?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.  If I call `bindService` from `onCreate` then `onServiceConnected` is in a race with the first call to `onHandleIntent`, so re-submit the intent if it arrives too soon.  My code is roughly like this.

```
class MyService extends IntentService implements ServiceConnection {
  IMyOtherService iService;

  @Override
  void onCreate() {
       bindService(intent);
  }

  @Override
  void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
       iService = IMyService.Stub.asInterface(service); 
  }

  @Override
  void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       if (iService == null) {
          /* onHandleIntent has lost the race with onServiceConnected
           * so wait 250 ms and resend the Intent.
           */
          try { System.getCurrentThread().sleep(250); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
          startService(intent);
       }
       iService->method1();
  }
```

Comment: You could use Service instead.