# How to bind service to another service

Tags: java, android, service, binding, bluetooth

i'm trying to write an android program where there are 2 service, one for bluetooth connection and another to call the method in bluetooth connection service. I'd like to know if i could bind these 2 services together, i tried but stuck

this code is from 2nd service when i tried to bind it to the bluetooth service

```
public class ActionHandler extends Service {

BTservice btService;    
boolean mBound = false;

 private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        ActionHandler getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return ActionHandler.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mBinder;

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent in, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Bind to Service
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,BTservice.class);
        bindService(intent,mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);   

    return START_STICKY;
    }


    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        btService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }


};
}
```

eclipse said that btService type mismatch, what should i do?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488445/could-a-service-bind-another-service